# How can i set exceptions for Metacity/GNOME window-styles?

Tags: firefox, themes, kde, metacity

I have KDE and Metacity as window manager enabled with a dark theme, but I'm having a few problems with it and firefox.
The default and my preferred style of firefox is light and not dark, but firefox adopts the dark theme of Metacity / Gnome and so my text boxes etc. are dark too, which looks horrible.

So my question is, how can i set exceptions or extra settings for Gnome so Firefox does not adopt the Gnome theme and set up a light one for it?

Btw, I'm using Kubuntu with Metacity as window manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one make firefox ignore my GTK theme entirely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8336/how-can-one-make-firefox-ignore-my-gtk-theme-entirely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered [here](/questions/8336/how-can-one-make-firefox-ignore-my-gtk-theme-entirely).

Shortly: Its actually the other way round. You don't tell gnome to skip firefox, you tell firefox to skip gnome.