# how to restore original thunderbird icon theme

Tags: icons, thunderbird

With Ubuntu 11.10, a dark-mono Thunderbird icon theme has been introduced. As I prefer the original in-app icons, I would like to ask, how to restore them.

Comment: I was hoping this would help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8336/how-can-one-make-firefox-ignore-my-gtk-theme-entirely but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a couple of icon themes using Tools/AddOns/Appearance. Some icon themes are not compatible with TB 7.X but Noia 2.0 and Nautipolis 1.8.77 seem to work fine. Both look pretty good also.

Comment: I have only the default icon theme installed, but in the previews there it shows full color icons. Thunderbird isn't *using* those, it is using these monochrome ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I cannot restore it too.

I remove ubuntu modified thunderbird then grab original thunderbird directly from its website.

Thunderbird will have original colored icon. :)