# Make firefox only use GTK theme on browser chrome, but ignore on websites

Tags: firefox, themes, gtk

I have a dark GTK theme, I don't want firefox to ignore it all together, I only want the theme to effect Firefox's chrome (the buttons, address bar, bookmarks bar, etc., etc.), but I want the theme to be ignored by websites, websites should not be themed by the browser! It's a sin, and it makes everything look like absolute crap. If anyone has any idea how to fix it, that would be great, thanks!

---

Edit: In the image below, the top panel shows that text entered in the search box is nearly invisible when the "dark theme" is applied; the lower panel shows text clearly visible when the dark theme isn't applied.

[image: Text in Google's search box]

Comment: It's my understanding that standard (light) gtk themes such as Ambiance or Radiance do not affect the appearance of web pages for the most part. There have been a few posts here when users of **dark** themes find the search boxes in Google and text boxes are affected. Could you edit your question to include images of Firefox with and without your dark theme? Mentioning your OS as well as the name and source of the theme may help as well.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.10, and yes, it's the form entries and combo boxes that usually get themed by the firefox theme. Here are some screen shots: http://imageshack.us/a/img571/1883/screenshotfrom201302140.png | http://imageshack.us/a/img687/1883/screenshotfrom201302140.png | http://imageshack.us/a/img14/4177/screenshotfrom201302140v.png | http://imageshack.us/a/img14/1883/screenshotfrom201302140.png

Comment: That did it! However I should note I had 2 .default folders, (past installs/ backing up config files), and I found an easier way to open your profile folder (I did this to figure out which one was active). If you open the Help menu, then Troubleshooting Information, then you'll see an entry Profile Directory with a button Open Directory, clicking on that button will open your active randomstring.default folder directly.

Comment: Also, you should have posted as an answer so I could give you some credit, vote you up ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope I understand your situation correctly. It seems somewhat related to [High contrast theme Firefox problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/183564/25656) and to [Need to modify gnome 3 theme for browser](https://askubuntu.com/q/227727/25656). And my answer below is essentially that which I provided to those questions!

Close (exit) all instances of Firefox.
Go to your profile folder. It is here: `~/.mozilla/firefox/randomstring.default`. In there, look for a subfolder called `chrome`.
If it doesn't exist, create it.
To create the `chrome` folder you can use your file manager (or the command line with `mkdir chrome`).
If `chrome` does exist, look for a file called `userContent.css`. Otherwise, create an empty text file with this name in the `chrome` folder.
Now open `userContent.css` with a text editor and paste in or append this code:

```
INPUT, TEXTAREA {color: black !important; background: #aaaaaa !important; }
```

Save the file (as plain text) and close the text editor.
Restart Firefox.
You should now have black text on a light gray background. You can use whatever color combination you prefer.

Notes: `chrome` and `userContent.css` are case-sensitive and should be spelled correctly. The settings here will take precedence over those in the OS theme and will remain the same in Firefox irrespective of which `gtk` theme you switch to.

Comment: I got a better result without the `!important` marker. If you leave it, the problem will be solved but all inputs that should be transparent became white.

Comment: I was also able to use unset.

`INPUT, TEXTAREA {color: unset; background: unset; }`

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I couldn't get the accepted answer to work, so I wrote a small [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script to achieve the same effect: https://gist.github.com/einarmagnus/d741e30ad13b051d7971

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        bright forms
// @namespace   einar
// @description Make all form elements default to light style to combat gtk theme
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
function addDefaultCssRules(rule) {
  var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
  styleElement.type = 'text/css';
  document.head.insertBefore(styleElement, document.head.firstChild);
  styleElement.sheet.insertRule(rule, 0);
}
addDefaultCssRules('input, button, textarea, select { background-color:#fff;border-radius:5px;color:#111 }');
```

This worked for me.