# How to make Firefox ignore GNOME's theme?

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes

I installed a new theme called Boje in my GNOME and it looks pretty good.

The problem comes when I open Firefox: I see that all HTML form inputs like, for example, textareas or simply text input have a dark style like my Gtk theme.

It is a problem for me because it makes all light websites looks a dark style, very ugly.

I was searching in the CSS of the theme but I don't find anything related to HTML elements and I don't know how I can do to fix this.

I've tried change my Firefox theme without success.

Comment: Have you checked this? :http://askubuntu.com/questions/8336/how-can-one-make-firefox-ignore-my-gtk-theme-entirely?rq=1 or this http://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio?rq=1

Comment: This answer of mine may help: http://askubuntu.com/a/256089/25656 for "I see that all HTML form inputs like, for example, textareas or simply text input have a dark style like my Gtk theme."

Comment: I wrote a CSS like Vasa1 said in his post and it works fine.