# Mediterranean themes for Unity - Change input form colors

Tags: 12.10, themes, colors

I've installed Mediterranean themes and I am using the dark one.
The problem is that @wolfram website the input form background color is black but the font is dark grey so it's difficult for me to use.

Although @askubuntu, while the input form of the title has a black background the font color is grey but visible.

Is there any way to change the color of the font I see in the input form at wolfram or I just have to cope with it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think your question is closely related to the one here: [Make firefox only use GTK theme on browser chrome, but ignore on websites](http://askubuntu.com/q/254479/25656). Do take a look at my answer there.

Comment: @vasa1: While this worked with wolfram and askubuntu, at google.com it appears as the screen the other user posted (white background, grey font). Do you know how could this be changed?

Comment: you haven't provided any images but I'll try to post a "generic" answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, themes cause problems with the way text is shown in forms and dropdowns in webpages. If one simple rule doesn't work for all sites, it maybe necessary to make site-specific rules.

If one is using Firefox, open and edit `/home/your_name/.mozilla/firefox/********.default/chrome/userContent.css` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/256089/25656) **except** that the actual matter to be added will depend on how the appearance of content of the web-page is to be modified.

For example:

```
@-moz-document domain("wolframalpha.com") { 
INPUT, TEXTAREA {color: black !important; background: #aaaaaa !important; }
}

@-moz-document domain("askubuntu.com") { 
INPUT, TEXTAREA {color: #aaaaaa !important; background: black !important; }
}

@-moz-document domain("google.com") { 
INPUT, TEXTAREA {color: blue !important; background: tan !important; }
}
```

For the Chrome (or Chromium browser), the use of an extension is required. I prefer [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe). This extension provides a GUI for making site-specific rules:
[image: Stylish site-specific rules]

and

[image: Stylish site-specific rule options]

(Stylish is also available [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)!)