# Firefox ignore GTK theme for localhost stuff

Tags: firefox, themes, gtk, colors

I know this is pretty much a duplicate of [How can one make Firefox ignore my GTK theme entirely?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8336/113651), but the answers on that one are no permanent solution. It works by launching firefox from the terminal.

I would like to know a solution that works for every instance of firefox no matter how it was created. There is the possibility to edit the userContent.css file, but the settings you make randomly do not apply to some sites or in some situations, strangely, even with the `!important` added...

I have a dark GTK theme and this results in some textboxes having a black background with black text with a userContent.css that has

```
input, textarea {
    color: black !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

### Update

I changed a setting in about:config from true to false, namely `browser.display.use_system_colors`. Everything appears normal and well now, for one exception: everything that runs on `localhost`. This includes PHPMyAdmin and a website I am making. I would like to know if there is a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to tell Firefox that it should use the light theme instead of the dark is by specifying the GTK_THEME variable prior to launching.

So, 3 ways you get for doing this..

1- from terminal you can do:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light firefox
```

2- if you hate the terminal and wanna close it once firefox works:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light firefox &
```

**3- if you want this to be the default behavior:**

Just add two lines to the Firefox launcher script located at /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh

**in the terminal type down:**

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

**look at the beginning of the script for this:**

```
MOZ_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/firefox
MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER=`which $0`
MOZ_APP_NAME=firefox

export MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER
```

**and change it to this:**

```
MOZ_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/firefox
MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER=`which $0`
MOZ_APP_NAME=firefox
GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light

export MOZ_APP_LAUNCHER
export GTK_THEME
```

**Finally, restart Firefox.**

Hope this helps.

Please help me by voting this up.

Thank you :)